# Django: customizing the field types needed for create and retrieve serializers

Tags: django-rest-framework, django-2.2

I currently have the following serializer:

`serializers.py`

```
class SurfGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    instructor = SurfInstructorSerializer(many=False)
    surfers = SurferSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SurfGroup
        fields = ['uuid', 'instructor', 'date', 'starting_time', 'ending_time', 'surfers']

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return SurfGroup(**validated_data)
```

And the following viewset create method (viewset inherited from `viewsets.ViewSet` as we need some bespoke customization, extra signals and actions etc):

`viewsets.py`

```
    # Surf Group Create View:
    def create(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = SurfGroupSerializer(data=request.data)

        serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)

        self.perform_create(serializer)

        headers = self.get_success_headers(serializer.data)

        response = responses.standardized_json_response(
            message='Surf Group Objects Have Been Successfully Created',
            data=serializer.data
        )
        return Response(data=response, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED, headers=headers)
```

For the retrieve action, the serializer works well, and we have a nested `instructor` object in the response. However, I want to perform a create by passing in the instructor `uuid` attrbiute like (see content in the POST textarea):

[image: django]

Rather than a whole object...I was wondering how we achieve this? Is it best to just have two Serializers, one for performing the create, and one the retrieval?

```
    def create(self, validated_data):
        surf_group = SurfGroup(
            instructor__uuid=validated_data['instructor'],
        )
        surf_group.save()
        return surf_group
```

Answer (score 0):

It is good question.

I work with this situations many times and it looks like one option is to have two serializers as you mean: 1 for list/retrieve and 1 for save.

Another option (for me) is to set serializer field input as UUID and output as another serializer data like this:

```
class SurfGroupSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    instructor = serializers.UUIDField()
    surfers = SurferSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SurfGroup
        fields = ['uuid', 'instructor', 'date', 'starting_time', 'ending_time', 'surfers']

    # I use this validate method to transform uuid to object which will
    # be bypassed to create method for easly save
    def validate_instructor(self, instructor_uuid):
        try:
            return Instructor.objects.get(uuid=instructor_uuid)
        except Instructor.DoesNotExist:
            # Remember that you dont need to pass field_key: [errors] to ValidationError
            # because validate_FIELD will automatically pass field_key for you !
            raise ValidationError(['Instructor with the given uuid does not exist.'])

    # Overwrite output data
    def to_representation(self, instance):
        ret = super().to_representation(instance)
        ret['instructor'] = SurfInstructorSerializer(instance=instance.instructor).data
        return ret
```